# JMS performance and RemoteTCPConnection.receive

Tags: java, ibm-mq

After paralleling JMS consumer threads, I did not get desired performance boost.
In jvisualvm I can see following jms stuff to be 'the winner' in self time CPU column.

```
com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.receive()
```

Here is full stack trace of what threads are actually doing.

```
"RcvThread: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection@9167029[qmid=MWTEST53_2019-06-10_12.32.59,fap=12,channel=MA                  ,ccsid=1208,sharecnv=10,hbint=300,peer=MWTEST/162.11.56.86(1453),localport=61965,ssl=no,hConns=0,LastDataSend=1583310588163 (16ms ago),LastDataRecv=1583310588163 (16ms ago),]" - Thread t@651
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.receive(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1535)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteRcvThread.receiveBuffer(RemoteRcvThread.java:794)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteRcvThread.receiveOneTSH(RemoteRcvThread.java:757)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteRcvThread.run(RemoteRcvThread.java:150)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"jms_reader_thread_9" - Thread t@63
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <711f08> (a com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteProxyQueue$GetterEventMonitor)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteProxyQueue.proxyMQGET(RemoteProxyQueue.java:2492)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiGetInternalWithRecon(RemoteFAP.java:6536)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiGetInternal(RemoteFAP.java:6432)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.internal.JmqiTools.getMessage(JmqiTools.java:1259)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiGet(RemoteFAP.java:6395)
        at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.InterceptedJmqiImpl.jmqiGet(InterceptedJmqiImpl.java:910)
        at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.ESEJMQI.jmqiGet(ESEJMQI.java:362)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQDestination.internalGetMessage(MQDestination.java:1012)
        - locked <1a7d0fa> (a com.ibm.mq.MQQueue)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQDestination.getInt(MQDestination.java:585)
        - locked <1a7d0fa> (a com.ibm.mq.MQQueue)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQDestination.get(MQDestination.java:456)
        at com.company.app.connection.MqConnection.nextRecordObject(MqConnection.java:351)
        at com.company.app.source.AppMqReader.next(AppMqReader.java:37)
        at com.company.app.source.AppJMSReadConnector.delegateNext(AppJMSReadConnector.java:202)
        at com.company.app.source.LegacyReadConnector.readNextWithRetry(LegacyReadConnector.java:114)
        at com.company.app.source.LegacyReadConnector.processNext(LegacyReadConnector.java:68)
        at com.company.app.source.AppJMSReadConnector.processNext(AppJMSReadConnector.java:435)
        at com.company.app.source.AppReadConnector.next(AppReadConnector.java:131)
        at com.company.app.source.AppReadConnector.next(AppReadConnector.java:114)
        at com.company.app.configuration.jaxb.ReadPipeline.run(ReadPipeline.java:262)
        at com.company.app.configuration.jaxb.AppAdaptor.run(AppAdaptor.java:684)
        at com.company.app.configuration.jaxb.RouteService.runOneIteration(RouteService.java:78)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractScheduledService$ServiceDelegate$Task.run(AbstractScheduledService.java:195)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractScheduledService$CustomScheduler$ReschedulableCallable.call(AbstractScheduledService.java:482)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractScheduledService$CustomScheduler$ReschedulableCallable.call(AbstractScheduledService.java:448)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Callables$3.call(Callables.java:89)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - locked <cc8421> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync)

        - locked <15571ee> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)
```

The thread is waiting! Almost all out of 10 threads are in `TIMED_WAITING` state. Here is code snippet of the `receive()` method logic

```
synchronized (this.getterEventMonitor) {
    if ((this.status & 0x4) == 0) {
        if (waitInterval > 0) {
            this.getterEventMonitor.wait(waitInterval);
        }
        else {

            this.getterEventMonitor.wait();
        }

    }
}
```

Status 0x4 should be `ST_GETTER_SIGNALLED`.

**Questions:** what is the logic behind waiting for `ST_GETTER_SIGNALLED` state, what the thread is actually doing and how could I make it faster?

Comment: As far as I understand it, IBM MQ is a closed source piece of software so I'm not sure how many folks on here will understand let alone be able to comment openly about implementation details.

Comment: Also, it doesn't appear that you're actually using JMS.

Comment: Do you have messages waiting on the queue to be consumed?  I would suggest setting the `SVRCONN` channel to have `SHARECNV(1)`.  By default IBM MQ sets this to 10 meaning there are 10 conversations per channel (meaning per TCP connection), this means things are multiplexed.  Setting it to 1 gives you a TCP connection per session.  Also if this is a JMS ASYNC listener, it will work in a call back mode as long as the Qmgr is v7.0 or later, so if no messages it will just be waiting on the QM with no activity on the client side.

Comment: Comment from you, Josh, was most useful, but I didn't got root cause of the issue yet, so I don't have anything to share.  I'm sure there are messages in input queue so this is not a reason of threads state. Indeed, by default SHARECNV is 10, and I was trying to make it 1 as suggested with no luck as I'm dealing with some custom application I'm writing dsl for and the only thing I'm able to do is to change application configs and configure 'routes'.

Comment: I didn't find the way to make that config be applied to test so again, I can't share anything useful. Justin is completely right but his comment doesn't help much. During these days I've found bottle necks with synchronous logging and DB calls, this is what was in my focus for 2 days, will compile everything together at the end.

Comment: The easiest way to change it is to set `SHARECNV` on the queue manager `SVRCONN`channel.  With JMS the only client side way to control this is to use a CCDT and set it on the `CLNTCONN` channel, otherwise JMS always defaults to 10.  The negotiated value is the lower betwen client and queue manger.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little more than a comment and, imho, a little less than an answer, but as it is too much text for a comment here goes.

You really need to describe when your threads are spawned and given work to do, as it is very difficult to work out what could be going wrong, but based on your statement that the threads are mostly in waiting state, then ...

... what could be happening is that if all 10 of your threads share the same `synchronised` logic, then at any given point, 9 of them will be locked out of this logic. The 10th, will wait until your check on `(this.status & 0x4) == 0)` is successful.

ie. if your 10th thread is in this logic and waiting, all the other 9 will be waiting for the 10th to stop waiting.

I think you need to rework the logic to have a single dispatcher thread that is monitoring for events, then dispatching a unit of work to waiting threads.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the basics of performance...
A piece of work is either running (using CPU),or waiting - using no CPU.

If there is no work to do then the thread will be in a wait.  Internally it may wake up periodically check the status and go back to sleep again.   In this case the "hot" routines using CPU will be those connected with timing.   Typically an MQ application  does a timed wait - MQGET WAIT for 10 seconds - so you will see " are in TIMED_WAITING state."

---

If you see the threads are in a wait state - then you need to find why messages are not being delivered to your threads.  If you threads are busy and spending more than 25% using CPU - you might want to check why they are using so much CPU - for example - are they doing data conversion or decryption.

---

Some basics
I presume these threads are consuming messages.
Are there messages for it to consume - for example display the curdepth of the queue.  If it is less than 10 - then some of your threads will be waiting.  If the curdepth is more than 10 then the threads should all be able to run and process messages.

Are the messages persistent or non persistent.
If they are non persistent then there is no disk logging, and it should take milliseconds get a message - so you should be able to see 100's of messages a second being processed on the queue.
If they are persistent, there will be disk logging involved  either at Get Out of syncpoint, or at the commit- this could be 1-10 (or more ) milliseconds.  So your task will spend most of its time waiting.

Going down a level.   Depending your version of MQ.  If you are doing puts or gets of persistent messages out of  syncpoint ( on distributed MQ) then a lock is held across the request to serialise access to the queue.   This may limit you to under 100 messages a second.  See here https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/2018/04/24/implicit-syncpointing-persistent-messages-put-outside-syncpoint/

You also need to think about are the messages going "get specific" or "get any"
For example your application does an MQPUT to a server, and then waits for the reply. (The so called request-reply or client model).  Even though there are messages on the queue, your thread will be waiting for a specific message.
if your applicaiton is a server, "get the first message on the queue, process it and send the reply back".   Then Any available message can be processed.